# Fastest way to compare an array against a (mysql) Table

Tags: mysql, comparison

i am scraping my head now for a long time and finally come back here to ask that question directly to you. Its quite a simple task but i am looking for the fastest solution. MySQL preferred but if you point me to something like Cassandra it would be great also.

1) Array with up to 1000 different entries of user-ID'S (bigInt)
2) SQL Table where this entires may occure in a column

So whats actually the fastest way to check if one of these id's occure in a row and return the matched rows.

Would you still do this by imploding the whole array of 1000 Entries and make something like FROM table WHERE field IN
???

Any hints, information would be highly appreciated!!!

Saludos Boosh

Answer (score 2):

> Would you still do this by imploding the whole array of 1000 Entries and make something like FROM table WHERE field IN ???

Yes. As in: `id IN (?, ?, ?, ...)`.

Or, if your DB supports arrays (MySQL doesn't), `id = ANY (ARRAY[?, ?, ?, ...])`.

Alternatively, if they're available using a small subquery, you can use:

```
id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a mass input of all the entries of your array into a temporary table, and then perform an inner join against the reference table to get the entries where the id is present in both table.

Regards

Comment: But the benefit of using a temporary table would be offset by the huge insert.

Comment: Possibly, yes. However, in SAP DB (using ABAP) this was faster than performing an "WHERE id IN ..." when you had to split the query into several one due to lmitation of the langage and/or DB